# Как отправить запрос POST или GET на сервер omnidesk

Tags: python, requests

Я применил следующий код, чтобы обратиться к omnidesk и создать [новое обращение](https://omnidesk.ru/api/cases#view_all_cases:%7E:text=%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-,%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F,-POST%20%20%7C%20%20https%3A//%5Bdomain)

```
import requests
import json
 
url = "https://test-123123.omnidesk.ru/api/cases.json"


data = {
  "case" : {
    "user_email" : "user@domain.ru",
    "user_full_name" : "User's full name",
    "subject" : "I need help",
    "content" : "I need help",
    "language_id" : 2,
    "custom_fields" : {
      "cf_25" : "some text",
      "cf_30" : "another field"
    },
    "labels" : [101, 102]
  }
}

params = dict(text=data)


res = requests.get(url, params=data)
res
```

```
<Response [401]>
```

Приходит эта ошибка, хотя по документации я все делаю правильно.
Возможно я не правильно делаю обращение через requests и мне нужно так же передавать api ключ, что бы создать обращение.

Comment: Во-первых, по ссылке post, а не get. Во-вторых, сложные структуры данных через params не передать. Отправляйте через тело запроса в виде json: `res = requests.post(url, json=data)`.

Comment: Ну и еще, используйте curl converter, на который вам ссылку дали под предыдущим вопросом, он отлично конвертирует curl запрос в python код: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zka72.png

Comment: Да ты прав. Я просто не совсем понял что мне нужно было сделать, а теперь я понял. Спасибо <3

Comment: Вот ссылка на сайт для конвертации curl в код на любом языке https://curlconverter.com/